# Silverlight 4 Async wait how to?

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous

I have a problem:

```
//Get All master record
entryE_QuestMaster = new ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster>();

 //Here I am calling my web service to get data
 QuestVM.getExamsMasterbyExamID(eUtility.ConvertInt32(this.txtID.Text), ref entryE_QuestMaster);

 //Loop to show questions
 int iNumber=1;
 foreach (var oIn in entryE_QuestMaster)
   {
      Node subNode = new Node();
      subNode.Content = oIn.e_Question;
      subNode.Name = "Quest_" + iNumber.ToString().Trim();
      subNode.Tag = oIn.e_QID.ToString();
      subNode.Icon = "/Images/Number/" + iNumber.ToString().Trim() + ".gif";
      iNumber++;
      this.tvMainNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);
    }
```

Whenever I call

```
QuestVM.getExamsMasterbyExamID(eUtility.ConvertInt32(this.txtID.Text), ref entryE_QuestMaster);
```

It runs the following code

```
 public void getExamsMasterbyExamID(int ID, ref ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionData)
        {
            ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionDataResult = iCollectionData;
            eLearningDataServiceClient client = new eLearningDataServiceClient();
            isSync = true;
            client.getExamsMasterCompleted+=(s,e)=>
                {
                    iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
                };
            client.getExamsMasterAsync(ID);

        }
```

My problem is I wanted to wait until my e.result comes back in `iCollectionDataResult`.

Currently after calling this service the system continues to the next line of code which is in the foreach loop. In this stage my entryE_QuestMaster does not have any record, I just wanted to wait till my result comes back before the loop continues.

**After Answering ChrisF**

no dought what chrisf said will work for me, but i wanted to do every thing in my MVVM class rather then in form level , here what i have change in my code , i still need your help guys and whated to do some professional code rather then just writing huge code.

i have added these two lines in my MVVM class

```
        public delegate void ShowQuestionTreeView(ObservableCollection<sp_GetQuestMasterbyExamID_Result> iResultQuestMaster);
    public event ShowQuestionTreeView ShowQuestionforTreeview;
```

then in method i have added this

```
  /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    public void getExamsMasterbyExamID(int ID, ref ObservableCollection<sp_GetQuestMasterbyExamID_Result> iCollectionData)
    {
        ObservableCollection<sp_GetQuestMasterbyExamID_Result> iCollectionDataResult = iCollectionData;
        eLearningDataServiceClient client = new eLearningDataServiceClient();
        client.getExamsMasterbyExamIDCompleted+= (s, e) =>
            {
                iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
                **ShowQuestionforTreeview(iCollectionDataResult);**
            };
        client.getExamsMasterbyExamIDAsync(ID);
    }
```

on client end i have done this

```
            //Generate Treeview for question
        QuestVM.ShowQuestionforTreeview += new eQuestCreateVM.ShowQuestionTreeView(QuestVM_ShowQuestionforTreeview);
```

method  :

```
  void QuestVM_ShowQuestionforTreeview(ObservableCollection<sp_GetQuestMasterbyExamID_Result> iResultQuestMaster)
    {
        //Loop to show questions
        int iNumber = 1;
        foreach (var oIn in iResultQuestMaster)
        {
            Node subNode = new Node();
            subNode.Content = oIn.e_Question;
            subNode.Name = "Quest_" + iNumber.ToString().Trim();
            subNode.Tag = oIn.e_QID.ToString();
            subNode.Icon = "/Images/Number/" + iNumber.ToString().Trim() + ".gif";
            subNode.Title = oIn.e_Question_Text;
            iNumber++;
            tvCreateQuestion.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(subNode);              
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this code:

```
       client.getExamsMasterCompleted+=(s,e)=>
            {
                iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
            };
```

outside your call to `getExamsMasterbyExamID`. This will also mean moving where you declare and initialise the `eLearningDataServicesClient`.

The way you have your code set up at the moment means that you are assuming that `iCollectionDataResult` will be set when the method returns. However, this is not the case. The method will return before the `getExamsMasterCompleted` event is fired.

You will need to organise your code along the following lines:

```
eLearningDataServiceClient client = new eLearningDataServiceClient();
client.getExamsMasterCompleted += (s,e) =>
{
    //Loop to show questions
}

client.getExamsMasterAsync(ID);
```

Or alternatively bind the display of questions to the ObservableCollection so when it gets set the UI updated automatically.

Comment: HI ChrisF: CAN YOU SEE THE CHANGES I HAVE DONE ?

Comment: @AQEEL: Do not use caps its bad precedent