# problem in silverlight 4 async how to wait till result come

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous

Here is what i have problem

i have following code :

```
  //Get All master record
        entryE_QuestMaster = new ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster>();
        QuestVM.getExamsMasterbyExamID(eUtility.ConvertInt32(this.txtID.Text), ref entryE_QuestMaster);
        //

        //Loop to show questions
        int iNumber=1;
        foreach (var oIn in entryE_QuestMaster)
        {
            Node subNode = new Node();
            subNode.Content = oIn.e_Question;
            subNode.Name = "Quest_" + iNumber.ToString().Trim();
            subNode.Tag = oIn.e_QID.ToString();
            subNode.Icon = "/Images/Number/" + iNumber.ToString().Trim() + ".gif";
            iNumber++;
            this.tvMainNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);
        }
```

here is async method calling wcf service

```
  /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    public void getExamsMasterbyExamID(int ID, ref ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionData)
    {
        ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionDataResult = iCollectionData;
        eLearningDataServiceClient client = new eLearningDataServiceClient();
        client.getExamsMasterCompleted+=(s,e)=>
            {
                iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
            };
        client.getExamsMasterAsync(ID);
    }
```

problem : when ever system run --> QuestVM.getExamsMasterbyExamID(eUtility.ConvertInt32(this.txtID.Text), ref entryE_QuestMaster);

its does not wait till i get e.result its just move to next line of code which is 
foreach loop.

plssss help any one or give idea with sample code what should i do to wait till e.result

i wanted to some how wait till i get e.result

any idea ?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question an hour before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight 4 Async wait how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224484/silverlight-4-async-wait-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution. Move the code that you want to execute after getting e.result in this loop.

client.getExamsMasterCompleted+=(s,e)=>
          {
                iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
            };

Answer (score 0):

Add an Action to the getExamsMasterbyExamID method, then execute the callback after is completed.

```
public void getExamsMasterbyExamID(int ID, ref ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionData,Action<object> callback)
{
    ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster> iCollectionDataResult = iCollectionData;
    eLearningDataServiceClient client = new eLearningDataServiceClient();
    client.getExamsMasterCompleted+=(s,e)=>
        {
            iCollectionDataResult = e.Result;
            //the callback will be executed on the calling method
            callback(e.Result);
        };
    client.getExamsMasterAsync(ID);
}
```

now when you call the Async method add the loop inside the callback like this:

```
    entryE_QuestMaster = new ObservableCollection<E_QuestMaster>();
    QuestVM.getExamsMasterbyExamID(eUtility.ConvertInt32(this.txtID.Text), ref entryE_QuestMaster,r=>
    {
        int iNumber=1;
       foreach (var oIn in entryE_QuestMaster)
       {
            Node subNode = new Node();
            subNode.Content = oIn.e_Question;
            subNode.Name = "Quest_" + iNumber.ToString().Trim();
            subNode.Tag = oIn.e_QID.ToString();
            subNode.Icon = "/Images/Number/" + iNumber.ToString().Trim() + ".gif";
            iNumber++;
            this.tvMainNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);
      }    
   });
```

after 2 months prob this wont be useful for the asker but maybe for someone else...